# Finding a GOP parameter value in video file using linux app and/or Python

Tags: python, linux

how can I discover the GOP parameter value in a video file using either existing linux app or python library?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step towards the solution is to get information about the frame number, time, is_key_frame information and frame type:

```
ffmpeg -i <FILENAME_HERE> -vf showinfo -f rawvideo -y /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -i showinfo | awk '{print $4, $6, $12, $13}'
```

What the command above really does is that it takes an input file and it extracts each frame out of it. When extracting, ffmpeg returns information about the currently processed frame on stderr.

Thus I have redirected the frame output into the /dev/null (otherwise it would save each frame as jpeg) and I redirected stderr to stdout using 2>$1. The rest is trivial, as I used awk to print only the relevant columns.

The second question is - how do I calculate GOP out of this data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mediainfo:

```
mediainfo myVideo.mp4  | grep GOP
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=61
```